# trying to replace words in a list with the position it comes in, in the sentence

Tags: python

```
from collections import OrderedDict
sentence= ("ask not what your country can do for you ask what you can do for your country").lower()
words = sentence.split(' ')

lst = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(words))
print(lst)
print(words)
```

In this code I have split the words individually in the sentence and made it into a list of the individual words that came up in the sentence. However, what I am looking to do further is how to replace the words in the list with the position it comes up in,in the sentence. I am fairly stumped and would kindly like some assisstance. Thank you :D

for instance, a desired output would be in the lst variable, the list would be:

```
['ask', 'not', 'what', 'your', 'country', 'can', 'do', 'for', 'you']
```

and under another variable perhaps, I would like the lit to come out with something like:

```
['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8']
```

therefore, under the whole sentence:

```
"ask not what your country can do for you ask what you can do for your country"
```

it would look like this:

```
['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8','0','2','8','4','5','6','3','4']
```

Comment: Don't forget to give us an example output - it helps quite a lot in case there's a linguistic confusion in the question. For instance, an example output might would be `final_list = [0, 1, 2, 3]` or something like that?

Comment: Please show your desired output; your sentence contains each word multiple times, so there's no _one_ index for each word. What kind of list do you expect?

Comment: So what you want is simply: `result = [for i in range(0, len(words))]`?

Comment: So, what is the difference of ths substitution you are asking for a simple list of ascending numbers

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you want to find *all* positional indexes of all unique words in your sentence, you can generate a `dict` as follows:

```
import pprint
sentence = ('ask not what your country can do for you ask what you can do for your country').lower()
words = sentence.split(' ')

# Use a dict and map all indices to each unique word
words_ix = {w: [] for w in set(words)}
for ix, w in enumerate(words):
    words_ix[w].append(ix)
pprint.pprint(words_ix)

# Use a list and collect the index of the first occurrence of each word
words_px = [words.index(w) for w in words]
pprint.pprint(words_px)
```

Yields:

```
{'ask': [0, 9],
 'can': [5, 12],
 'country': [4, 16],
 'do': [6, 13],
 'for': [7, 14],
 'not': [1],
 'what': [2, 10],
 'you': [8, 11],
 'your': [3, 15]}

[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 2, 8, 5, 6, 7, 3, 4]
```

Choose whatever solution suits your needs.

Comment: I was thinking to loop through the string and adding the first index of each word to a list. But this is better, nice and clean too.

Comment: This is better than my answer if every position of the word is needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't explicitly need an `OrderedDict`, you can do it quite simply using `set` and `index`.

```
sentence = ("ask not what your country can do for you ask what you can do for your country").lower()
words = sentence.split(' ')

pos_dict = {}

for word in set(words):
    pos_dict[word] = words.index(word)

print pos_dict
```

We create an empty dictionary, then loop over the `set` of unique words found in our sentence. Then we use `index` to find the position of the word in the initial list we created to find its first occurrence.

EDIT: Since the edit of the question, there's a nice one-liner to get the result out:

```
sentence = ("ask not what your country can do for you ask what you can do for your country").lower()
words = sentence.split(' ')

word_pos = [words.index(word) for word in words]

print word_pos
```

returns `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 2, 8, 5, 6, 7, 3, 4]`

Answer (score 0):

try the following code:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
sentence= ("ask not what your country can do for you ask what you can do for your country").lower()
words = sentence.split(' ')

lst = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(words))
numberLst = []
for word in words:
    # print lst.index(word)
    numberLst.append(lst.index(word))

print(words)
print numberLst # numberLst is the output that you want
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will help you:

```
sentence = "ask not what your country can do for you ask what you can do for your country"
words = sentence.split(' ')

new = [str(words.index(x)) for x in words]

print(words)
print(new)
```

Answer (score 0):

This version assigns consecutive numbers (starting from zero) to each new word. It uses a plain dictionary to track which words have been seen, and we can simply use the current size of the dictionary as the index number for each new word.

```
sentence = "ask not what your country can do for you ask what you can do for your country"

d = {}
lst = []
words = sentence.lower().split()
for w in words:
    if w in d:
        i = d[w]
    else:
        d[w] = i = len(d)
    print(i, w)
    lst.append(i)

print(lst)
```

**output**

```
0 ask
1 not
2 what
3 your
4 country
5 can
6 do
7 for
8 you
0 ask
2 what
8 you
5 can
6 do
7 for
3 your
4 country
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 2, 8, 5, 6, 7, 3, 4]
```

---

Note that the `i` number of a word is *not* the index of the first occurrence of the word in the sentence. If you actually want that, you can use

```
lst = [words.index(w) for w in words]
```

as jbndl suggests in the comments.

See what happens when we repeat a word before all the unique words have been added to the dictionary:

```
sentence = "ask not what your country can not do for you"
```

**output**

```
0 ask
1 not
2 what
3 your
4 country
5 can
1 not
6 do
7 for
8 you
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 6, 7, 8]
```

Comment: Way too complicated; this falls down to `[words.index(w) for w in words]`.

Comment: @jbndlr Your list comp is clearly more compact than my code, but it is O(n^2) (albeit the O(n) of `words.index` is running at C speed) whereas mine is O(n). But my code doesn't always give the same result as yours, as shown in the 2nd example sentence I just added.

Comment: Oh, right. I wasn't aware of that edge case in your solution though. Good thing you pointed that out, it might become important if this solution is used.

Comment: @jbndlr At this stage, it's not totally clear exactly what the OP wants, so I figured I'd give them this option. :)